# Transparent Activity with background activity click through behaviour in android

Tags: android, android-activity

Hi `stackoverflow` I'm trying to develop an application with a base activity and a `Transparent` activity, so far I'm able to create a `Activity` and a `Transparent` activity over base activity using follwing code

`MainActivity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    startActivity(new Intent(this, TransparentActivity.class));

    findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Main", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
}
}
```

`TransparentActivity.java`

```
public class TransparentActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_transparent);

    findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(TransparentActivity.this, "Btn1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
}
```

`styles.xml`

```
<resources>
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

`Manifest`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.test"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.test.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.test.TransparentActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

`activity_main.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="52dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

`activity_transparent.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="29dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="44dp"
    android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

But I want the `Base Activity` to be touchable as well along with `TransparentActivity`. Please some one help me to solve this strange riddle.
Thanks.

Comment: Use broadcast to communicate between activities

Comment: Thanks @Ali Imran But I want to keep on displaying the transparent activity, also I need the base activity to be responsive as well.

Comment: @ChethanShetty have you got any answer..

Comment: No solutions yet @kalyan pvs

Comment: @ChethanShetty i have posted my solution check it..i am tested it is working..

Comment: Will you please edit the transparent acitvity in your answer please @kalyan pvs if you don't mind, cause I'm not getting it to work, I tried exact like your solution

Comment: ok..wait...i will edit..and post again..

Comment: I updated the answer..check it..the problem in second activity layout..change it to linear its working..

Comment: Hi @kalyanpvs... u got both the activitiy's elements touchable?

Answer (score 4):

Add these lines in the Transparent Activity above `super.onCreate()` method.

```
getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
            LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);

    // ...but notify us that it happened.
getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
            LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH);
```

transparent layout like this..

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="8dp" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="29dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="44dp"
    android:text="Button" />
```

Comment: No use, problem still continues

Comment: Only tranparent activity button is touchable, the Bse activity is not tochable

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40737/discussion-between-chethan-shetty-and-kalyan-pvs)

Comment: Hi @Delcasda u got both the activitiy's elements touchable?

Comment: Hi @kalyanpvs you added two statements. In second Statements how will it notify when touch the tranparent activity?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code on your foreground activity

```
getWindow().addFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
```

Comment: Thanks @Paulo Barbosa after adding the code, my Transparent/Foreground activity is not touchable now.

Comment: is this possible to touch both background and foreground

Comment: It works but crashes with the system buttons (back, home)

Answer (score 0):

Same as user1544148 answered but with a small change:
remove the WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE flag

```
getWindow().addFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);
```